# Sending messages from facebook App to the User

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

After google search, all most all the posts said it is not allowed to send messages from Facebook App to friends. May be I did not understand completely what the other people are saying about sending messages.
Is it allowed to send messages from a facebook app to the user who added the app to his account? (Not to the user's friends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:  email and through the application dashboard.

It is not possible to send a mesage to a user's Facebook message inbox from an application.

Some info on emailing users:  http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/355

Info on the dashboard:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/dashboard.addnews/

Answer (score 0):

You can use FBML to invite friends.[FBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/friend-selector/)